# Java List.contains(ArrayList<String> with field value equal to x)

Tags: java, list, search, contains

Using the code below I am able to check if a `List` of Objects contains field matching specific value.

```
public boolean containsName(final List<MyObject> list, final String name){
    return list.stream().filter(o -> o.getName().equals(name)).findFirst().isPresent();
}
```

However, this works only when `o.getName()` returns a `String`. I am trying to modify the code so this works when `MyObject` contains an `ArrayList<String>` and name can match any element in the list. Something like this:

```
public boolean containsKeyword(final List<KeywordPOJO> list, final String keyword){
    return list.stream().filter(o -> o.getKeywordList().equals(keyword)).findFirst().isPresent();
}
```

Where `KeywordPOJO` returns a list of keywords instead of a single `String`. If `keyword` matches *ANY* of those keywords method should return true.

At the present moment, Eclipse throws warnings: `Unlikely argument type for equals(): String seems to be unrelated to ArrayList<String>` (because keyword is a String and `getKeywordList()` returns `ArrayList<String>`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `List.contains`:

```
o -> o.getKeywordList().contains(keyword);
```

As a side note, your expression could be simplified with `Stream.anyMatch`:

```
public boolean containsKeyword(final List<KeywordPOJO> list, final String keyword){
    return list.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getKeywordList().contains(keyword));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What if `keyword` was actually a `List` and not a `String`? `list.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getKeywordList().contains(keywordList))` won't work..

Comment: @S.O.S In that case you can use `.containsAll(keywordList)` (assuming you want to check that all keywords are present)

Comment: but I want it to return true if any one of the keywords in list match.. I believe `containsAll(keywordList)` will return true only if all match.. correct?

Comment: @S.O.S That's right (and that's why I added *...assuming...*). If you want to check that the list contains at least one of the keywords, you can use `return list.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getKeywordList().stream().anyMatch(o::equals));` (just be careful with empty lists, because `anyMatch` returns `true` if the stream is empty - I think)

Comment: Thanks for the response so far. Just wanted to clarify one thing: `return list.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getKeywordList().stream().anyMatch(o::equals));` Will this evaluate  whether `KeywordPOJO` in List contains any Object that contains any keyword from `keywordList` (parameter)? The method will be accepting following parameters: `final List<KeywordPOJO> list, final ArrayList<String> keywordList`

Comment: @S.O.S Correct. It kinda translates to *"if any `KeywordDensityPOJO` in `list` has a keyword list in which at least one element is equal to `keyword`, then return `true`"*. It will only return `false` if `keyword` is **not** found in any `keywordList` of any `KeywordDensityPOJO`

Comment: `keywordList` is another list supplied to method as parameter - not the one returned by `KeywordPOJO.getKeywordList()`. In other words,"if any `KeywordPOJO` in `list` has a keyword list (as returned by `getKeywordList()`) in which at least one element equals at least one keyword from parameter `ArrayList<String>keywordList` return true. Method signature: `public boolean containsKeyword(final List<KeywordDensityPOJO> list, final ArrayList<String> keywordList){
  
  
  return list.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getKeywordList().stream().anyMatch(o::equals));
 }` I Hope this clarifies my point..

Comment: @S.O.S Right, that's exactly what I meant :)

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing:

```
list.stream().filter(o -> o.getKeywordList().equals(keyword)).findFirst().isPresent();
```

by:

```
list.stream().filter(o -> o.getKeywordList().contains(keyword)).findFirst().isPresent();
```

or shorter:

```
list.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.getKeywordList().contains(keyword));
```